# Incrementing of variable by clicking

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas and I want to increase variable *voltage* by clicking. The problem is that when I click - variable increase by some random amount. I need one click = variable increase by one.

Here's the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("diodeCircuit");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var voltage = 0;

function runCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  changeVoltage();
}

function changeVoltage() {
  window.addEventListener("click", doMouseClick, false);

  function doMouseClick(event) {
    x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 1000 && y >= 0 && y <= 400) {
      voltage += 1;
    }
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText(voltage + " V", 500, 50);
}

setInterval(runCanvas, 100);
```

Link to project on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Arkej/pen/bEQQaB?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(runCanvas, 100);
```

This is calling your `runCanvas` function 10 times a second - which is calling `doMouseClick` function, which creates 10 click listeners every second, and by clicking you fire each of those listeners.

Move this:

```
window.addEventListener("click", doMouseClick, false);
```

outside of your interval function callbacks so that you end up with only one click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `eventListener` from `setInterval` and call it from outside of `setInterval` , its repeatedly attaching the click eventlistener to the window:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("diodeCircuit");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var voltage = 0;

function runCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  changeVoltage();
}

function doMouseClick(event) {
  x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  if (x >= 0 && x <= 605 && y >= 0 && y <= 332) {
    voltage += 1;
  }
}

function changeVoltage() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText(voltage + " V", 500, 100);
}

window.addEventListener("click", doMouseClick, false);
setInterval(runCanvas, 100);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <canvas id="diodeCircuit" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```